# put hellip (...) to a text that is inside of bar in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a chart in which there are bars and am currently doing that if the text does not fit on the bar, then right out of the bar.

```
d3.selectAll('.c3-text')
      .each(function(d){
      var self = d3.select(this),
      width = +d3.select('.c3-zoom-rect').attr('width');
      if (+self.attr('x') + self.node().getComputedTextLength() > width){
      self.attr('x', '5');
      }
});
```

Now I want the text if not fit on the bar, are added ellipsis (...) and the text is cut to the width of the bar.

when the bar is very small, I need the text left out and also with ellipsis far end of the screen.
[image]

Thank you very much.

https://jsfiddle.net/e00vfofo/

Answer (score 0):

For longer bars use style or css 'overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis;' - this automatically truncates and adds ellipsis to text that overflows.

For short bars take the text out as you are doing already and add `&hellip;` to the end of the string.

Comment: What doesn't work? - Presumably adding &hellip; to the end of text works...

So, the other bit doesn't - well, in pure javascript it works for me (always), assuming the text overflows the width of the div/container.